# setting a min character in a regular expression on ()

Tags: javascript, regex

**/^[a-z]+[0-9]*$/igm**

Tom //true
tom12123 //true
12tom //false
to12m //false
T23 //true
T //true but I don't want it to be. I want a min of two characters.

**/^([a-z]+[0-9]*){2,}$/igm**

Tom //true
tom12123 //true
12tom //false
to12m //true should be false
T23 //false but I want it to be true
T //false

Why does this require the second character to be a letter? Why can't it be min 2 characters the first letter can be followed by more letters. Then numbers can be at the end? 2 letters would pass and one letter and 1 number would pass.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear. If you want at least 2 alpha chars, followed by any number of alphanumeric chars do this:

```
/^[a-z]{2}[a-z0-9]*$/i
```

If you want at least 2 alphanumeric chars, followed by any number of alphanumeric chars do this:

```
/^[a-z0-9]{2,}$/i
```

If you want 2+ alpha chars, followed by optional numbers do this:

```
/^[a-z]{2,}\d*$/i
```

If you want 1+ alpha chars, followed by optional numbers, and at least 2 chars overall do this:

```
/^(?=..)[a-z]+\d*$/i
```

Note: `(?=..)` is a positive lookahead for 2 chars

You don't need the `g` flag if you anchor at the beginning and end. You don't need the `m` flag if you have a single line.